# Issue with Ember Server. TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: node.js, ember.js

Hello I'm trying to run ember server. I installed nodejs, npm and bower.

```
jose@jose:$ ember server
version: 0.0.37
object is not a functionTypeError: object is not a function
    at /home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:103:25
    at visit (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/utilities/DAG.js:23:3)
    at DAG.topsort (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/utilities/DAG.js:82:7)
    at Project.initializeAddons (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:90:9)
    at EmberApp._notifyAddonIncluded (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:110:16)
    at new EmberApp (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:106:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jose/code/frontend/Brocfile.js:7:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.loadBrocfile (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli/lib/builder.js:147:14)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:15:26)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.init (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:32:10)
    at new Class (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/core-object.js:18:12)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/tasks/serve.js:15:19)
    at Class.module.exports.Command.extend.run (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/commands/serve.js:35:18)
    at Class.Command.validateAndRun (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:74:15)
    at /home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:53:22
    at $$$internal$$tryCatch (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:470:16)
    at $$$internal$$invokeCallback (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:482:17)
    at /home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1066:13
    at $$rsvp$asap$$flush (/home/jose/code/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1531:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Could be any missing dependency?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: the version you are using is a little outdated.  it is possible to be a dependency issue, maybe you are using older version of cli on a newer version of node?  Try installing the new CLI version .46 and see if you have the same issues.

Comment: Yes, it is a problem of versions. I had to install the new version of CLI and then add some third-party libraries to my bower.json and package.json one by one.

Thanks @Grapho